# JQuery crop image clientside keeping also the original version

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I read a lot of discussion and answer about client side image cropping with JCrop, but I cannot find a solution for my problem.

I have a large form generated with simple_form that has an image inside (with others input_fields)

I want to upload this image, but before the form submission I need to crop this image and, at the same time, **upload (and keep) also the original version**.

I think that my situation is standard: you have a blog, you load the post image and you need to adjust the image for the teaser, cropping it.

If I edit my post later, I have the original version for a new crop.

I'm thinking about two solutions:

1) Crop image clientside using this plugin: http://evrone.github.io/evroneCrop/, but I don't know how can I manage the base64 encoded image with Carrierwave.

2) Use JCrop JQuery Plugin to obtain crop data, pass the crop data in hidden field with my form and use Carrierwave to create the cropped version, following the Ryan Bates tutorial.

The second solution doesn't look difficult, but I loose trace of my cropped version: when I edit my post I want to see the two versions and, if needed, crop my original image in another format.

Which is the best way to implement this situation, considering that I'm not so skilled with javascript?

Comment: I could give you some ideas if you don't mind having a conversation in the comments about how to get it working?

Comment: Okay bud - let me get something done & I'll give you some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, there are two ways you could do it:

1. Upload image & then crop in 2 separate calls
2. Upload crop data separate to image, and use ImageMagick to crop (with Paperclip && possibly with a queue) (single call)

I guess both cases are similar (to your (2))

Either way, to keep this programatically sound, I'd want to keep an original image for later. Reason being you can always crop an original, but you can't "uncrop" a cropped image

---

**Upload First Then Crop**

Since you're using Ajax already, why don't you try this:

- User selects image
- Ajax uploads image
- You present the image & use JCrop to define cropping dimensions

---

**Upload & Crop With One Call**

You could upload the image & crop in the same call

You alluded to this process in your (2) idea. To do this, you are correct in that you'd have to store the crop co-ordinates in hidden fields

I've never used `jCrop` before, but according to the [jCrop manual](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html), you can call the co-ordinates relatively simply:

```
function showCoords(c) {
      // variables can be accessed here as
      // c.x, c.y, c.x2, c.y2, c.w, c.h
};
```

You could change various hidden input's values with the co-ords you need, thus providing the data you need

You could then add several columns to your image db:

```
images
id | paperclip / carrierwave columns | x | y | x2 | y2 | w | h | processed (boolean)
```

This will allow you to store the original image (as per Carrierwave / Paperclip), as well as save its co-ords

Then you'd be able to either create a processing file which will run through & process the images, creating a new cropped image

I can look to write some code for this if you're interested

Comment: @rickpeck I think that the second solution is fine.

I create an image upload form. When I upload the image I load jcrop to have the cropped version. On submit I pass using as hidden fields also the "crop coordinates" (that I add to the model) and in my model, "before_saving", I crop the image using CarrierWave and the coordinates.

When I edit the form I use the saved coords to create the "previous cropping zone" in my preview, than I can adjust.

Looks fine, I will try. Thank you

Comment: @rickpeck. I finish the "ruby" part. The problem is the jquery part... is not easy to bind jcrop on the "preview" windows of the form...

Comment: What do you mean Roberto?